# Remove extra line after adding/deleting a bookmark in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks, blank-line

In My Word Template I have few bullet points, and I will select the required points based on selection from the GUI and remove the rest of the points  that are not selected from the code. So it depends on the user how many points that he would select.

- I am Tall (bookmark1)
- I am Dark (bookmark2)
- I am 6.2 feet height (bookmark3)
- I Have BMW (bookmark4)
- I know 5 different languages (bookmark5)

I have created bookmarks for all these points as shown in the braces above.

Now the problem is, the user selects few number of bullet points from the above list and output would leave an extra blank line below.

I have tried many approaches from changing the selection of the bookmarks to adding bullet point form the code. I need to get rid of the extra blank line.
But nothing seems to work. I would appreciate the help in this. TIA

```
If .cboChanges1.Value = "No" Then
     DeleteBookmark ("bookmark1")
Else
     AddBullet ("bookmark1")
End If
If .cboChanges2.Value = "No" Then
     DeleteBookmark ("bookmark2")
Else
     AddBullet("bookmark2")     
End If
```

etc.. where cboChanges1 and cboChanges2 are combo boxes to choose Yes/no.

```
Sub DeleteBookmark(strBookmark As String)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(strBookmark).Range
    rng.Delete
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Before Screenshot
[image]

Output screen after first 3 options, you can see extra blank line as highlighted
[image]

I am adding the bullet point dynamically, as follows

```
Sub AddBullet(strBookmark As String)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(strBookmark).Select
    Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
End Sub
```

This is how the bookmarks are arranged,
[image]

Comment: To help you we need to be able to reproduce your issue, but there isn't enough detail in your question to do that. As you haven't posted your code we can't see what you have tried either.

Comment: Added few snippets, hope this will help to understand better. Also to give more details the bullet points are enclosed with in a table

Comment: To assist in understanding your document please include before and after screenshots showing the table with the bullets. Please ensure that both bookmarks and hidden formatting marks are shown.

Comment: "Please ensure that both bookmarks and hidden formatting marks are shown." - To show the formatting marks press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `8`. To show bookmarks go to File | Options | Advanced | Show document content | Show bookmarks. Unless these marks are shown we cannot see how you have constructed the table. From what little that can be seen it looks as though you have a paragraph that isn't being deleted.

Comment: The details have been provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table cell always contains an end of cell marker which is a combination of paragraph and end of cell mark. This means that an empty cell always contains at least one paragraph.

As the end of cell marker cannot be deleted when you delete the text in the last bookmark you will get an empty paragraph because the previous bookmarked range ends with a paragraph mark.
[image]

You can deal with this in your DeleteBookmark routine by checking the length of the final paragraph of the cell. If it only contains two characters then it has no text and the preceding paragraph mark can be deleted.

```
Sub DeleteBookmark(strBookmark As String)
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(strBookmark).Range
   rng.Delete
   Set rng = rng.Cells(1).Range.Paragraphs.Last.Range
   If Len(rng.Text) = 2 Then
      'paragraph contains no text so delete preceding paragraph mark
      rng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
      rng.MoveStart wdCharacter, -1
      rng.Delete
   End If
   Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you are going to write code for Word you need to learn what the formatting marks are so that you can understand how a document is constructed.

FYI It is not necessary to select a range to apply bullets.

```
Sub AddBullet(strBookmark As String)
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(strBookmark).Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: @Puneeth - please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Timothy Thanks a Ton That worked for most of the scenarios I tested. But will the same solution work for ? say, few bookmarks with no bullet points, but with in a table as above. For example, Bookamrk1, b2, b3 and I delete b2 and it leaves many extra blank lines between b1 and b3, based on the size of the bookmark. Or else is there any different approach?

Comment: @Puneeth - if there are "many extra blank lines" those lines must contain non-printing characters that you haven't deleted.

Comment: Timothy I will open a new thread if required.

Comment: How can we remove if there are many extra blank lines in between bookmarks, as said in the above example?

Comment: @Puneeth - if there are "many extra blank lines" those lines must contain non-printing characters that you haven't deleted. You need to analyse your document to see what those characters are, and ensure that your bookmarks include the paragraph mark.